# Rails add attachment before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have an App that uses Paperclip to add attachments to an asset.  You can add a new attachment once the asset has been created by clicking on the "Add attachment" link, however I would like the same link for a new asset.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your attachment a separate model or is it just an attribute of an asset? In the latter case, it won't work with the link, since you do not have an existing Asset record. However, you could then include the file selection field directly in the form for the new Asset.

In the former case, have a look at Railscasts [196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), where Ryan Bates explains how to accomplish this with nested forms.